Error deleting data from txt Android Studio/java
I I have an application that saves some data in a txt to be able to manage subscriptions to Firebase notifications.
Simply when you subscribe to a topic, that topic is saved in a txt so you can later retrieve the list and unsubscribe from those topics.
I have a class "Settings" in which a list of subscriber topics appears from which I can unsubscribe.
I also have the "detailmovie" class from where I call the same method to unsubscribe. From the settings class it works but from the PeliculaDetalle class it doesn't.
They call the same method of the "SuscripcionUtil" class.
This is de Suscription class
public class SuscripcionUtil {

    // Método para eliminar una suscripción del archivo notificaciones.txt
    public static void eliminarSuscripcion(Context context, String tema) {
        try {
            // Obtener el contexto de la aplicación
            Context applicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();

            // Obtener la ruta del archivo notificaciones.txt
            String filePath = applicationContext.getFilesDir() + "/" + "notificaciones.txt";
            File file = new File(filePath);
            Log.d("SuscripcionUtil", "Ruta del archivo: " + filePath);

            // Verificar si el archivo existe
            if (file.exists()) {
                // Leer el contenido del archivo y eliminar la línea correspondiente al tema
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Si la línea no contiene el tema, la añadimos al nuevo contenido
                    if (!line.startsWith(tema + ":")) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("SuscripcionUtil", "Se encontró una línea a eliminar: " + line);
                    }
                }
                reader.close();

                // Escribir el nuevo contenido al archivo
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
                writer.write(stringBuilder.toString());
                writer.close();

                Log.d("SuscripcionUtil", "El archivo se ha actualizado correctamente.");
            } else {
                Log.d("SuscripcionUtil", "El archivo notificaciones.txt no existe.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    // Método para obtener las suscripciones guardadas en el archivo notificaciones.txt
    public static ArrayList<String> obtenerSuscripciones(Context context) {
        ArrayList<String> suscripciones = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            // Obtener la ruta del archivo notificaciones.txt
            String filePath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "notificaciones.txt";
            File file = new File(filePath);
            // Verificar si el archivo existe
            if (file.exists()) {
                // Leer el contenido del archivo
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Separar el nombre y el push
                    String[] parts = line.split(":");
                    if (parts.length >= 2) {
                        suscripciones.add(parts[0]);
                    }
                }
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return suscripciones;
    }

    // Método para mostrar un mensaje Toast
    public static void mostrarMensaje(Context context, String mensaje) {
        Toast.makeText(context, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // Método para desuscribirse de los temas seleccionados
    public static void desuscribirseDeTemasSeleccionados(Context context, ListView listView, ArrayList<String> suscripciones) {
        SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        int itemCount = listView.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            if (checkedItems.get(i)) {
                String tema = suscripciones.get(i);
                // Desuscribirse del tema en Firebase Messaging
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(tema);
                // Eliminar la suscripción del archivo de notificaciones
                eliminarSuscripcion(context, tema);
                // Mostrar mensaje de desuscripción exitosa
                mostrarMensaje(context, "Desuscripción exitosa de " + tema);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void guardarSuscripciones(String nombre, String push, Context context) {
        String contenido = nombre + ":" + push + "\n";

        try {
            // Abrir el archivo notificaciones.txt en modo append (para añadir al final)
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "notificaciones.txt", true);
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
            printWriter.print(contenido);
            printWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void desuscribirseDeTema(String tema, Context context) {
        // Desuscribirse del tema en Firebase Messaging
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(tema);
        Log.d("SuscripcionUtil", "Desuscripción de Firebase Messaging para el tema: " + tema);
        // Eliminar la suscripción del archivo de notificaciones
        eliminarSuscripcion(context, tema);
        Log.d("SuscripcionUtil", "Eliminación de suscripción en el archivo para el tema: " + tema);
    }


}

Here i call the function from settings (working)
private void mostrarDialogoGestionNotificaciones() {
        // Obtener las suscripciones guardadas
        ArrayList<String> suscripciones = SuscripcionUtil.obtenerSuscripciones(this);

        // Crear un diálogo personalizado
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Gestión de Notificaciones");

        // Configurar la lista de temas suscritos
        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, suscripciones);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); // Permitir selección múltiple
        builder.setView(listView);

        // Configurar el botón de desuscribirse
        builder.setPositiveButton("Desuscribirse", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                SuscripcionUtil.desuscribirseDeTemasSeleccionados(AjustesActivity.this, listView, suscripciones);;
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss(); // Cerrar el diálogo
            }
        });

        // Mostrar el diálogo
        builder.show();
    }

Here i call the function from PeliculaDetalle (not working)
notificacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isNotificacionEnabled) {
                    // Si el usuario está suscrito, desuscribirlo
                    SuscripcionUtil.desuscribirseDeTema(push,PeliculaDetalleActivity.this);
                    notificacion.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    notificacion.setText("¡Avísame!");
                    isNotificacionEnabled = false;
                } else {
                    // Si el usuario no está suscrito, suscribirlo
                    SuscripcionUtil.guardarSuscripciones(nombre, push, PeliculaDetalleActivity.this);
                    notificacion.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
                    notificacion.setText("Quitar aviso");
                    isNotificacionEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        });

This activity verifies if the topic is already suscribed or not. The verification works and I can suscribe to new topics succesfully but I can't unsuscribe from this class.
I dont know why because it's all the same
I tried modifiyng the context, creating a new class to manage the suscription methods and check the permissions. Everything looks fine to me.

whats the error

no error, it just dont work. It doesn't delete the line in the txt
